# Change value of query parameter using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, query-string

I need to change the value of query parameter present in the given URL using jQuery.

There are 2 possible URL's like,

```
www.domain.com/?id=10&name=xxx
```

and

```
www.domain.com/?name=xxx&id=10
```

I need to change the value of parameter **id** in this URL into something like `www.domain.com/?id=15&name=xxx`. Regex seems to be the solution for this, but it looks confusing to me.

**Possible solution:**

Select the string between **"id="** and **"&"** (or) string from **"id="** to the end of string and replace it with desired value 15.

Does anyone have solution for this or any other better solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you google search your title you will get a lot of answer to your question

Comment: Of course I did. But none seems like the exact solution.

Comment: Have you had a look at [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)? There's even a [JS polyfill](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/url-search-params) for browsers that don't support it natively.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where is this URL that you are wanting to change? Is it the actual URL for the page on which you are running? Is it an `href` in an `<a>`? In addition, you also need to tell us *exactly* what you want, not "something like ..." Does what you said mean that you want both `www.domain.com/?id=10&name=xxx` and `www.domain.com/?name=xxx&id=10` changed to `www.domain.com/?id=15&name=xxx`? Do you really care what the order is (it's *possible* that order matters, but usually it doesn't. You just haven't told us what you actually want)?

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question which results in invalidating an Answer, is against policy on Stack Overflow. Your edit here did so. The policy is that other users should proactively revert such changes. I have done so here. You *are encouraged to [ask a new Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)*, perhaps with a link to this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Comment: @Makyen Sure. I'll ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var url="www.domain.com/?id=10&name=xxx";
changeUrl("id",15);
changeUrl("name","sumesh");
function changeUrl(key,value){
  var patt = new RegExp(key+"=[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
  var matches = patt.exec(url);
  var id2 = matches[0];
  url = url.replace(id2, key+'='+value);
  console.log(url);
}
```

Use `RegExp` to achieve this.

Comment: The parameter "id" is just an example. I need generic regular expression which also must suite for changing the parameter "name".

Comment: Generic means how ? do want change entire query string?

Comment: You have given regex for integer. Consider I have a function which accepts parameter and the value. If I pass (id, 15) or (name, yyy) this method should work.

Comment: At least use `[0-9]+`, or better, just the [character class `\d+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes).

Comment: @VinothKumar That's not what your question asks for. If you wanted that, then you needed to have it *in your question* and *before people answered*. You will need to create a new question to ask for the generalization that you appear to want, as changing a question such that you invalidate answers is against policy.

Comment: @SumeshTG Thanks. It works for what I asked for. I need to ask separate question for your solution. Anyway, I upvote your answer.

Comment: @SumeshTG Alphanumeric characters are not the only ones that are valid in query values. Your line `var id2 = matches[0];` will throw an exception if the `key` field does not exist in the URL. Both your RegExp to find the original value and your `url.replace` will silently fail, producing erroneous results, if there are fields (query parameters) which are too similar (e.g. the query is `fooid=100&id=10` and you try to change `id`).

Comment: @Makyen You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simple replace?

```
var newUrl = location.href.replace("id="+10, "id="+15);
```

I found this solution from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17212004/2225787) to the question
[Change url query string value using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17211736/change-url-query-string-value-using-jquery) (marked as duplicate).

Comment: But I don't know the value "10" since it is random. How can I handle this?